# QAction to close QMainWindow behaves inconsistently only in IPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, ipython, pyqt5

I want a QMainWindow which the user can close by: clicking the window close button, clicking an item in a menu, or using a keyboard shortcut. This is my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMainWindow)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    '''A simple window'''

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.make_gui()

    def make_gui(self):
        '''Create main GUI window'''
        self.menuBar()
        self.statusBar()
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon(None), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Actions')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = QApplication([])
    GUI1 = Window()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

When I run this code with python, this works every time, no matter which of the three actions is used to close the window. When I run it in IPython, one of these behaviors may happen:

1. Everything works as expected.
2. On exit, the window does not close.
3. On exit, the window does not close, and IPython exits.
4. On launch, warnings start to appear in the IPython shell. More appear
   when interacting with the application. After these warnings first appear,
   they will appear on every subsequent launch
   until IPython is restarted.

Warning examples:

```
QWindowsContext::windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x1c (WM_ACTIVATEAPP), hwnd=0x0xb0dd8.
QWindowsContext::windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x2a3 (WM_MOUSELEAVE), hwnd=0x0xb0dd8.
QWindowsContext::windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x24a (WM_POINTERLEAVE), hwnd=0x0xb0dd8.
QWindowsContext::windowsProc: No Qt Window found for event 0x1c (WM_ACTIVATEAPP), hwnd=0x0xb0dd8.
```

My environment: Python 3.7.2 64-bit on Windows 10.